# SQL - Find productID that doesn't have shadows containing a substring as productID

Tags: sql

I have the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100
Product.ID
FROM db.Product
WHERE 1=1
 AND ShadowOf = '' --This means that the product isn't a shadow itself, but a shadow parent, containing shadows.
 AND Product.ID NOT IN (select ShadowOf from Product WHERE ShadowOf <> '') --This makes sure that the product doesn't have any shadows.
 Order By Product.ID ASC
```

A shadow is basically like a copy of the product that contains the same attributes and values, images, etc.

The table goes like this:

```
ID  |ShadowOf|Shadows
A   |        |B
B   |    A   |
B.TE|    C   |
C   |        |B.TE
```

1. The same product can have multiple shadows;
2. The same product can be a ShadowOf only one other product;
3. A product that is already a shadow of another product can't have shadows of it's own.

**What I need to do:**

Find all Product IDs that are not Shadows(meaning ShadowOf values for them is empty) and don't have shadows that end in ".TE"(They can have any other value in the Shadows column)

**What I tried to do:**

```
AND Product.ID IN (SELECT ShadowOf FROM Product WHERE ShadowOf NOT LIKE '%.TE')
```

**What am I expecting to get based on the sample table above:**

ID
A

Because A is the only product that is NOT a shadow, and doesn't have a shadow ending in .TE

Edited some mistakes.

Comment: Please post the full query you need help with, some sample data, and the desired result.

Comment: You need to specify some sample data. It's impossible to tell from your question what the types of values in `Product ID`, `ShadowOf` and `Shadows` are, and without that information the question can't be answered properly.

Comment: Edited. Not sure what else I can add, but let me know. It's a rather simple exercise, but I seem to be unable to get what I want with what I tried and I've spent like 2 hours trying to figure it out with various options.

Comment: I would post the full query with everything in it, but it's close to 4 A4 pages on font size 12 and I don't think I can post so much here. Note that the comments on the first blocks of code is what I get as a result. I think I can do it on the production if I get it to work on a simple table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a product can have multiple shadows, a `NOT EXISTS` clause is probably the most practical solution:

```
WHERE 1=1
  AND Product.Status=1
  AND ShadowOf = ''
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Product p2 WHERE p2.ID = Product.ID AND p2.Shadows LIKE '%.TE')
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8e6ff2/1)

Comment: Thanks. This actually solved the issue from what I tested so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter a little your query to get the result

```
Select DISTINCT a.ID
From Product a 
Where (ShadowOf = '' or ShadowOf is null) 
AND Product.ID NOT IN (SELECT distinct ID FROM Product b WHERE Shadows LIKE '%.TE')
```